SQL Server procedure locks tables from another database
I have a procedure in database DB_A that inserts some data into the table Table_A in the same database.
This is a pretty simple procedure. However, I see that the process that runs the procedure stays in a SUSPENDED or RUNNING state for a very long time, more than 30 minutes.
The weirdest thing is that this process locks 2 other tables in another database that are not related to the procedure at all.
Procedure looks like this:
use DB_A;
go

create procedure dbo.spAddUrls @sURL nvarchar(500), @dtDate date
as
begin
    set nocount on;

    declare @nID_ bigint = dbo.ufnGetHash (@sURL);

    begin try
        begin tran
            insert into dbo.TableA (ID, [URL], MapDate)
            values (@nID_, @sURL, @dtDate);
        commit transaction
    end try
    begin catch
        declare @ErrorMsg varchar(1000) = error_message();

        if @@trancount > 0
        begin
            rollback transaction;
            raiserror (@ErrorMsg, 8, 1);
        end
    end catch
end

But I see exclusive locks on database DB_B on two unrelated tables Table_B and Table_C.
Table_A in DB_A doesn't have any triggers or foreign keys.
Why do tables in DB_B get locked?
Note: all these tables and the procedure are part of the replication. But I'm not sure it's related.

The solution to the puzzle was that before the call of the stored procedure, there were MERGE statements with Table_B and Table_C.
And what is most important, at the very beginning of the session there was a set implicit_transactions on statement, which held an open transaction until the end of the session.
Thanks to all.


The weirdest thing is that this process locks 2 other tables in another database that are not related to the procedure at all.

With some exceptions, locks are held until the end of a transaction.  So the locks held by that session may have been acquired by a previous statement.
